# Where can I find the known values for the number-of-groups-function upto $10,000\ $?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, groups-enumeration

OEIS shows the number of groups of order $n$ upto $2047$.
The Magma-online-calculator uses a database, but already for $1024,2004,2016,...$ it cannot determine the number of groups. Maple seems to calculate the number of groups (unless it is too large), but unfortunately, I do not have access to maple.

> Does anyone know an online-calculator for the number-of-group-function, or a table with the known numbers upto $10,000$ or more ?
>
> Or alternatively, allows PARI/GP, at least in principle, to calculate the number of groups of order $n$ ? I programmed the case $n$ squarefree, but I have no clue how to manage arbitary numbers $n$.

Comment: There isn't any general formula or algorithm known for computing the number of groups of a given order $n$, other than to construct all of them. Maple uses formulas for certain special cases, depending on the factorisation of  $n$ (for instance, for square-free $n$, or for small powers of primes, etc.) and uses a table of known values for small $n<50000$. I expect GAP and Magma have something similar, but I don't know that PARI has that kind of functionality.

Comment: @James I was just curious. By the way, in the answer below, it is claimed that the number can be calculated in the case $p^2 q^2$. Do you know the formula ?

Comment: It's my understanding that some sort of formula or description is known, but I do not know it!  I've never been able to get my hands on the papers where it is described.

Comment: For four primes, the situation is as follows.

The case $p^4$ and the squarefree case are well-known.

The case $p^2qr$ was done by Glenn (1906)
http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1906-007-01/S0002-9947-1906-1500737-3/S0002-9947-1906-1500737-3.pdf

As far as I can see, the number of isomorphism type is not explicitly stated, but perhaps could be extracted with a little more work.

Comment: The case $p^3q$ was done by Western (1898)
http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s1-30/1/209

His count is at the end.
15 groups when $q=2$.
6 or 19 groups when $q=3$ and $p$ odd. (For $p=2$, there are $15$.) 
etc...
Take all of this with a grain of salt, for example, according to magma, there are $7$ groups of order $3\cdot 5^3$.
Moreover, his count in the table is also off for 189 and 351.

Comment: As for the case $p^2q^2$, there is 
-Cheissin (1940) in Russian
http://www.mathnet.ru/links/60d16d15641beeb3d01618e6fcc20a64/im3913.pdf
-CHEN Songliang (2009) (in Chinese)
http://en.cnki.com.cn/Article_en/CJFDTOTAL-HZSZ200904002.htm

It has an English abstract and claims the following formula that, assuming $p$ and $q$ are odd, there are either 4,6,7,11, or 15 groups

This also seems wrong, according to magma, there are 13 groups of order $441=3^2\cdot 7^2$, whereas he predicts $7$.     
Last reference: Lin, Huei Lung
On groups of order $p^2q$, $p^2q^2$. 
Tamkang J. Math. 5 (1974), 167–190.

Comment: I suppose the takeaway is that, while these results are within reach in principle, some of the computations are a bit delicate, especially when trying to count the classes. (Rather than just give a complete but possibly redundant list, which is much easier.)

Answer (score 4):

For the list of $n$'s which are included in the SmallGroups library, see : 
https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/727

There are many missing n's which could be computed, even by hand (when $n=p^2q^2$, for example), but there are definitely some numbers less than $10000$ that are out of reach.

For example, the number of groups of order $2048$ is not actually known, higher powers of $2$ even less so, see for example
https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/gnu.pdf

(This is a good reference for your question in general.)